# Effect sizes from regression analysis and factor loadings

Tags: regression, pca, effect-size

To do a meta analysis, I try to calculate effect sizes. In [an article by Shah and Ward](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0272696302001080), the authors do a regression analysis after combining various factors by a CPA to four factors. The factor loadings are provided in the article. The beta coefficients for these four factors regarding operational performance (a factor of dependent variables) are given too.

Is it possible to calculate effect sizes for the independent variables with this information? Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking about principal components regression, beta coefficients are effect size estimates. Are they not the ones you want?

Comment: These estimates give only information about the factors which were calculated by the factor analysis. My question is if and how to calculate the effect sizes between the "original" variables and the dependent factor.